# XML retrieve an item with his attribute?

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I have a XML like that :

```
<DescriptionsComplementaires>
    <DetailDescriptionComplementaire lang="fr" libelle="Descriptif" type="16.01.04">
        <Description lang="fr" libelle="Tarifs en clair" type="16.02.67">Gratuit</Description>
    </DetailDescriptionComplementaire>
    <DetailDescriptionComplementaire lang="fr" libelle="Descriptif" type="16.01.04">
        <Description lang="fr" libelle="Présentation, descriptif commercial" type="16.02.30">Chaussure de marche conseillées. De 12h à 14h sur présentation du ticket remis au départ: Apéritif offert par la commune des Haies Assiette dégustation de produits du terroir offerte pas la communauté de communes. Petit marché de producteurs locaux. Animations et stands d'information. Exposition "les 100 paniers du monde" Café et buvette. 
        </Description>
    </DetailDescriptionComplementaire>
</DescriptionsComplementaires>
    ........
```

How can i retrieve item with libelle="XXX" in php ? I use DOMDocument().

Edit :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('(629)_ListeOI_fr_20120720_043502.xml');
$attr = "Présentation, descriptif court";
$query = "//*[@libelle='{$attr}']";
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query($query);

foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    //i don't know what to do here for display items
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DomDocument xpath

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml_string);
$attr = "Descriptif";
$query = "//*[@libelle='{$attr}']";
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$entries = $xpath->query($query);
```

to iterate results : http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Comment: Can you help me for my example ? I need to retrieve all "Présentation, descriptif commercial" in my XML.

Comment: I have a foreach : foreach ($entries as $entry) {  }, how can i display all values of $entry ?

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's SimpleXML::XPath http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php instead of your approach. Your code will be simplified, would look something like this:

```php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr); 
$res = $xml->xpath("//*[@libelle=XXX]"); 
print_r($res);
```

Comment: And with my example ? I need to load an .xml first

Comment: load xml file with ```$xmlStr=file_get_contents("name.xml")``` and then you can use the about code.